# pymysql-How to return the results of a query in the form of a list of tuples

Tags: pymysql

Lets say I have this code:

```
sql_query="select actor.actor_id from actor where actor='%s'"
cursor.execute=(sql_query,(actorID))
result=cursor.fetchall()
return(result)
```

What should I do to my code so the results are in the form of a list of tuples?Also I want the first tuple to be the name of the columns of my query.

```
For example: [(“Name”, “Id”,),(“Jim”,7,),(“Tom”,13,)]
```

Comment: You can make results a list by passing the list keyword in fron or results after the fetchall() Line. results = list(results)

Comment: I edited my question cause I forgot to say something

Comment: Why do you want commas after values such as 7 and 13 within the tuples?

Comment: To get the tuples however, you could run a for loop on each tuple in results, and then append that tuple to an empty list. That will give you a list of tuples.

Comment: I added an answer but I am missing something

Comment: How do i get the row I want to append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another answer that simple grabs the column names and stores them in a nested tuple:

```
cur.execute('''DESCRIBE patient_login''')
results = cur.fetchall()
nested_tuple_list = []
nested_tuple_list_2 = []

for result in results:
   result = ((result[0]))
   nested_tuple_list.append(result)

nested_tuple_list = tuple(nested_tuple_list)
nested_tuple_list_2.append(nested_tuple_list)
print(nested_tuple_list_2)
```

The describe command in SQL will Describe the table by telling you which columns exist within the table, and various characteristics of the table such as primary key, datatype ect. This command will return a tuple of the described data. Here we search each result and grab the first index in the results for each of the nested tuples. The first index corresponds with the column name in the for loop. We can append this to the first empty list. After we append all of the column names, we change the list to a tuple. We then append that tuple to the list and have all of the column names in the list within a tuple. Here is the output:

```
[('ID', 'username', 'password')]
```

If you want each element in the list to be a tuple in it of itself, here is the code:

```
nested_tuple_list = tuple(nested_tuple_list)
nested_tuple_list_2 = [(x,) for x in nested_tuple_list]
print(nested_tuple_list_2)
```

We can do a list comprehension with x representing each column, and here is our output for each of my columns in the DataFrame:

```
[('ID',), ('username',), ('password',)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample example:

```
cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM patient_login''')
results = cur.fetchall()
nested_tuple_list = []

for result in results:
   nested_tuple_list.append(result)

print(nested_tuple_list)
```

As you can see, we enter our select statement with cur.execute(). We fetch all of the results and store them in the variable results. We run a for loop, and each result will be a tuple of a result in our DB. We then append them to the end of the list. When we print the results, here is the output:

```
[(4, 'sikudabo', 'monkey1'), (83, 'sikudabo2', 'monkey2')]
```

We end up with a list of tuples.

Comment: I used a pseudo example since I do not have your code for your specific database, but this is the gist of what you need to do.

Comment: And all I have to do if I want the first line to be the column names is nested_tuple_list = [(col1,),(col2,)(col3,),]?

Comment: If you want the first line to be the field names (name/id) you can add them to the list first. You can do something such as: nested_tuple_list = ('name', 'id'), And then after that you can run the rest of the code and append the additional values to the list.

Comment: yeah I meant if i want the comlumn names instead of doing this nested_tuple_list = [] to do this nested_tuple_list = [(col1,),(col2,)(col3,),] in your code.

Comment: Also did you meant there    nested_tuple_list.append(result) or    nested_tuple_list.append(results)?